# Как узнать откуда метод

Tags: php, ооп

Незайтеливый вопрос про ООП, код упрощен для понимания.

```
abstract class Two {

}

class One extends Two{
    $res = $this->parent->get($id, array(...));
}
method_exists('One', 'get')); // false
```

Two абстрактный, его бессмысленно проверять. Вопрос: где искать метод get?

Comment: Очевидно там, где он есть. Например если он реализован в абстрактном классе

Comment: А parent - это переменная?

Comment: что есть $this->parent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите в объекте `$this->parent` собственно. Данное свойство хранит ссылку на экземпляр какого-то вашего объекта, у которого и вызывается метод `get`...

**Просто способ, чтобы узнать, экземпляр какого класса это свойство — выведите:**

```php
print_r($this->parent);
```

И либо в этом классе метод объявлен, либо он наследуется, либо в самом классе или наследуется есть перегрузка методов `__call` — нужно выяснять.

А лучше пользоваться какой-нибудь IDE, например, PhpStorm. В ней достаточно «нажать» на данный метод и «магическим» образом перейдете на объявление метода, если он там объявлен...